# Add own key=value pairs to config.txt to use it with vcgencmd get_config

Tags: raspbian

I would like to add own key value pairs to the `config.txt` to use these values with `vcgencmd get_config`. In my test it did not work. I was just able to use `vcgencmd get_config` with the original key value pairs from Raspbian.

Is there an easy hack to add own key value pairs that can be used?

Comment: Why would you want to put parameters in the `config.txt` file?

Comment: Its a nice central place for configuation.

Comment: No, it's really not...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add custom key value pairs to `vcgencmd get_config`.

Comment: Ok then I'll write a separate function for it.